# How to pick an image from gallery,crop and save that in data partition

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bitmap, gallery

i need some help
i want pick an image from gallery after that re size it to custom size for example to 480*800 ,then put it in a folder of data partition(for example(/data/test_wall)).
i tried Google search many times but noting.

here is my code till now but i cant pick from gallery and save image give me force close:

```
package com.example.walpaperpicker;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int PICK_FRPM_GALLERY = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PickPic();
        }

        private void PickPic() {
            // this code working for pick a picture with camera
             Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, PICK_FRPM_GALLERY);

            // this code not working give me fc after i select picture from gallery see my logcat
            /*Intent GallaryIntent = new Intent();
            GallaryIntent.setType("image/*");
            GallaryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(GallaryIntent, PICK_FRPM_GALLERY);*/


        }
    });
}
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_FRPM_GALLERY) {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ImageView test = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                test.setImageBitmap(photo);
                try {
                    //I want put it in data partition but i dont know this is for sdcard
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/wallpaper.png");
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

/*i want crop output picture
 *to custom size for example 480*800
 *but i dont know.
 */
  }
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.walpaperpicker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"> </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"> </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.walpaperpicker.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this code working  if i take picture from camera and will save it in "/sdcard/wallpaper.png"
but i don't want pick a picture from camera and put it in "sdcard" .
i want first pick an image from gallery,crop it to 480*800 
then put that in a folder of data partition(i have rooted device) .see my above codes.

here is my log-cat

```
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241): Process: com.example.walpaperpicker, PID: 5241
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:26274 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.walpaperpicker/com.example.walpaperpicker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3368)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3411)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:138)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at com.example.walpaperpicker.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:50)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5433)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3364)
01-31 02:27:37.545: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     ... 11 more
```

thanks for helping
i am waiting .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written couple of articles on How to pick Gallery Image or Thumbnail, will help you

> [**How to Pick Image from Gallery in Android**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-pick-image-from-gallery-in.html)
>
> And
>
> [**How to pick the Image thumb-nail from gallery in android**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-pick-image-thumb-nail-from.html)

Okay let me try to explain how it works

**1. we need to create an intent for picking image from Gallary**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore  
                              .Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

**2. In the same activity we need to handle picked image in onActivityResult method**

```
@Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,   
                                     int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE &&   
                              resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {  
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();  
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };  

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,  
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);  
            cursor.moveToFirst();  

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);  
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);  
            cursor.close(); 

            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            //here you can call createImageThumbnail method passing (picturePath,480,800) 
            //and set the received bitmap imageview directly instead of storing in bitmap.
            // eg. imageView.setImageBitmap(createImageThumbnail( picturePath, 480, 800));


            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory  
                            .decodeFile(picturePath));  

        }  


    }
```

**3. resize the Image as you want ( Width * Height )**

```
Bitmap createImageThumbnail(String imagePath, int width, int height) {  
  BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();  
  bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;  
  int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight  
    / (float) height);  
  int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth  
    / (float) width);  

  if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1) {  
   if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {  
    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;  
   } else {  
    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;  
   }  
  }  
  bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;  

  if (bitmap != null) {  
   bitmap.recycle();  
   bitmap = null;  
  }  

  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmpFactoryOptions);  
  return bitmap;  
 }
```

Let me know if you have any trouble in this.Happy to help.

Comment: thanks buddy,i tried your code and i have problems with re size and i think you forgot i want putout put picture in a folder of data partition    

  `// imageView.setImageBitmap(createImageThumbnail( picturePath, 480, 800));`



  `bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;  

     if (bitmap != null) {  
      bitmap.recycle();  
      bitmap = null;  
     }
     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmpFactoryOptions);  
     return bitmap; 
     //i have errors with bitmap and imagePath(this is not should be "picturePath"??) cant in lines above let me to compile
    
 }`